# gfortran "not linked" after installing with 'brew install gcc'

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, gfortran, macos-sierra

I need to use fortran so I have installed gcc from homebrew

```
brew install gcc
```

i couldn't compile my source code so i tried to reinstall

```
Warning: gcc-6.2.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

so i tried to link it

```
brew link gcc
```

with this result

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/gfortran
Target /usr/local/bin/gfortran
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

so i tried this

```
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

which gave me this result

```
Error: Could not symlink include/c++/6.2.0
/usr/local/include/c++ is not writable.
```

As i am pretty new to this I'm now stuck but i desperately need to resolve this so i can continue my uni work at home, please help